# flutter navigation pop to different screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-null-safety

i use

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => B()));
```

to push from A to B to C to D
i need to pop back from D to B
i also need to remove D and C form stack
i used

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route is B);
```

but it gives me a blank screen it works only with initial route,
sloutions i found is to use

```
Navigator.pop();
```

twice

is there any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can set route name.

```dart
Navigator.push(
  context, 
  MaterialPageRoute(
    settings: RouteSettings(name: '/B'),
    builder: (context) => B(),
  ),
);
```

When you call `popUntil` set parameter using this name.

```dart
Navigator.popUntil(
  context, 
  ModalRoute.withName('/B'),
);
```